# If trim is used in Select, does it have to be used in Where?

Tags: sql

This should be an easy question.

If the trim function has been used on an ID in a Select statement, does it have to be used on the ID in a Where clause? Or can the trim function be left out in the Where clause?

```
SELECT (TRIM(a.T$ID)) as "ID" 
FROM SCHEMA.DDiitm0011 a
WHERE TRIM(a.T$ID) LIKE '4U%'
```

Comment: It depends - do any of the column values you want to match have leading spaces - like `'   4Uxyz'`? That would match with trim, and not without. Trailing spaces don't matter though, as they'd be covered by the wildcard %.

Comment: There is no requirement that columns or expressions in the SELECT should appear in the WHERE or vice versa. You can filter on one column and return another.

Comment: That's a good question. I actually want to exclude ID's that start with 4U. Would this WHERE clause suffice? WHERE (a.T$ID) NOT LIKE '4U%'

Comment: Yes you can use NOT LIKE '4U%'

Comment: @Alex Poole, sorry, I meant to tag you earlier. Would I need to modify this WHERE clause to capture all instances where the ID starts with 4U? Or would it be okay, as it is, even if there are leading spaces before the 4U? WHERE (a.T$ID) NOT LIKE '4U%'

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You should always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Oracle SQL Developer. I did add 'Oracle SQL Developer' as a tag, so I'm not sure why it's not showing up....?

Comment: @Mr2017 - that's a client, not a database; it probably means you're using an Oracle database but not necessarily. You can add the Oracle tag if you are.

Comment: Ok, thank you for responding. I'm curious to know how I'd work out which database I'm using? I thought Oracle SQL Developer was a DBMS, and lots of search results give that impression. But I'm curious to know how you'd work out what the DBMS is? You're the most knowledgeable person I've come across on this site.

Comment: @Mr2017 - I would have thought you'd know before you tried to connect to it. If it's Oracle you can `select * from v$version` (from any client), which will confirm that and tell you the version. No idea for other databases though I'm afraid, but that query should fail if it isn't Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

> If the trim function has been used on an ID in a Select statement, does it have to be used on the ID in a Where clause?

There is no general requirement for the function to be applied in both places. It depends on the data and the logic you need to apply to your exclusion filter, and - separately - how you want to return the matching values. You won't get a syntax error if you trim in the select list and not the where clause, or vice versa; but you might not get the result you want if you use the wrong expression(s).

> I actually want to exclude ID's that start with 4U. Would this WHERE clause suffice? WHERE (a.T$ID) NOT LIKE '4U%'

Yes, though you don't need the parentheses either:

```
SELECT (TRIM(a.T$ID)) as "ID" 
FROM SCHEMA.DDiitm0011 a
WHERE a.T$ID LIKE '4U%'
```

That will exclude values starting with `4U`, such as `'4U'`, `'4U '`, `'4UP'`, `'4UNDER    '` etc.

It will *not* exclude any that have spaces before that, such as `' 4U'` or `'   4UP'`.

If you wanted to exclude those as well then you could use `TRIM(a.T$ID)` or `LTRIM(a.T$ID)` (to only remove leading spaces, not trailing ones - which are covered by the wildcard `%` anyway). Or you could use a regular expression, but those tend to be significantly more expensive. Either way, applying a function to the column value would prevent a simple index on that column from being used, if it otherwise would be, but you could add a function-based index if that was an issue.

Comment: Ok, awesome - that's really useful context!!! Thank you @Alex Poole! Not sure how to tag people on here, but I hope you get this message of gratitude! And Happy Friday!

Answer (score 0):

You can use TRIM in WHERE clause like that for example :

```
DECLARE @ExampleVarTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, Name1 VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @ExampleVarTable (Name1)
VALUES('  Toto '), ('Toto'), ('Titi'), (' Titi   '), ('  Toto')

SELECT ID, TRIM(Name1) 
FROM @ExampleVarTable
WHERE TRIM(Name1) LIKE 'Toto'
```

Result :

```
ID  Name1
1   Toto
2   Toto
5   Toto
```

But you should make this kind of request :

```
SELECT ID, TRIM(Name1) 
FROM @ExampleVarTable
WHERE ID = 3
```

Result :

```
ID  Name1
3   Titi
```